# Rounding up to the next 10 cents (dime) in C#

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I would like to format decimal numbers to the **NEXT** 0.10 cents (dime) in C# like so:

22.62  ->  22.70
23.50  ->  22.50
23.21  ->  23.30
23.03  ->  23.10
23.10  ->  23.10
23.14  ->  23.20
23.17  ->  23.20
23.11  ->  23.20

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

What I have so far:

```
Math.Round(22.621, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) //gives 22.60 
Math.Round(22.656, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) //gives 22.70
```

Comment: `23.10` will be `23.10` but `23.50` will be `22.60`? Are you sure?

Comment: 23.50 will be 23.50 sorry edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method will get the answer you're looking for:

```
decimal RoundToNextDime(decimal d)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(d*10)/10;
}
```